# MYSQL using TYPE 'ALL' in explain plan

Tags: mysql

in mysql query, i have indexed a column but which doesn't use index at all. Following is the plan of mysql query. The first column table lmt is not using index. please help me with some suggestions.[image]

Comment: Provide a query and table schema + details such as how many rows im `lmt` and how many of them are selected?

Answer (score 6):

Type column in MySQL explain result show that How MySQL joins the tables used. This is one of the most insightful fields in the output because it can indicate missing indexes or how the query is written should be reconsidered.

All – the entire table is scanned to find matching rows for the join. This is the worst join type and usually indicates the lack of appropriate indexes on the table.

Its clear in your Query explain result, that no Key is getting used and whole table lmt has been scanned. So, always try to avoid this case for improving your query performance.

Beside, MySQL explain documentation, please follow the below [URL](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) to understand the EXPLAIN result in details.

Comment: Thanks for your post usditesion. I have indexed column loan_item_id but mysql isn't using it. May i know why?

Comment: MySQL execute the best query plan according to your table structure, available indices and your SQL query. If index is not getting utilized you have to focus on all these things first. It may be required to add composite index. Order of columns in the composite index is important.